# Insert a new row into oracle sql table with date field

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I am a newbie to SQL.

I have a table called

```
x with fields:
       name,
       id,
       hire_date
       ......
```

`hire_date` is in `date(01-jun-98)` format.

Now i wanted to insert a new row into table x, where:

```
`the hire_date is in 'mon-dd-yyyy hh:mi:ss' (july-21-2014 13:00:00)format.`
```

i tried using to_char, to_date, convert functions but im not successful. Do i have to alter the table x(change the hire_date date type to above mentioned ones) before inserting this new row? I have tried these already

```
insert into x values( 'james',201,'july-21-2014 13:00:00')
```

Comment: Should this be tagged MySql?

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?  In Oracle, if a column is actually of type `date`, it has no format.  The only time that you'd properly talk about a column with a "format" would be if you had a `varchar2` column where you were storing the string representation of a date.  You don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into x 
values( 'james',201,to_date('july-21-2014 13:00:00', 'month-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```